# error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified. (Can't connect to my local db)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following connection string in my web.config :

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" 
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

When I try to connect to my local database `aspnetdb.mdf` from my local iis server everything works fine, but when I put the site in the other server, I get this error message :

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified).

(in the other server I have SQL Server 2008 installed).

Comment: possible duplicate of [error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified. (Can't connect to my local Db From my host server)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820168/error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified-cant-connect-to-my-local)

Answer (score 0):

> (in the other server I have SQL Server 2008 installed).

Looks the the Sql Server 2008 installed on other server does have the same instance name as shown in the `connectionstring data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;`

Please update the data source with the correct name also make sure if it requries user id/password or not

Comment: Hi @HatSoft, I really appreciate your help,How can I check the instance in sql server ?

Comment: @wben If you can log on that server and look in to services (run services.msc from commandline) you should see Sql Server(instance name)

Comment: This is what I can see in the following picture : http://stream.tutowall.com/pic/sqlservice.png

Comment: @wben I would suggest you give the name like this 
e.g. IP Address\InstanceName

Comment: but why giving the Ip Adress ? my database (aspnetdb.mdf) is stored in the app_data folder !