# Deploy .net mvc site on shared hosting

Tags: .net, iis

Connection String at my shared hosting look like:
"Data Source=SQL5004.Smarterasp.net;Initial Catalog=DB_9A9FD8_steamfish;User Id=DB_9A9FD8_steamfish_admin;Password=YOUR_DB_PASSWORD;

In my Web.config i have connections section:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnections" connectionString="Data Source=SQL5004.Smarterasp.net;Initial Catalog=DB_9A9FD8_steamfish;User Id=DB_9A9FD8_steamfish_admin;Password=YOUR_DB_PASSWORD" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.BaseModel.csdl|
         res://*/Models.BaseModel.ssdl|
         res://*/Models.BaseModel.msl;
         provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
         provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=SQL5004.Smarterasp.net;Initial Catalog=DB_9A9FD8_steamfish;User Id=DB_9A9FD8_steamfish_admin;Password=YOUR_DB_PASSWORD&quot;"
  providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

P.S. YOUR_DB_PASSWORD replaced on my password

Why i have error:
provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified

I solved the problem. I recompilier my project whith new settongs.

Comment: i am using smarterasp and your i had no problem with connection string. you should check your app and connection string.

Comment: what exactly i need check ?

Comment: may be `provider connection string=&quot;` this part? in entities

Comment: If i delete all Entities section i have same error

Comment: what about `DefaultConnections` is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You may check out these questions:

[error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified. (Can't connect to my local Db From my host server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820168/error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified-cant-connect-to-my-local)

and

[SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754563/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified)

Most of them suggest you check your 'Data Source=SQL5004.Smarterasp.net' part again.